# Python Parameter passing for another function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have created two functions namely inputData(): and validateNumber():
In the inputData() function I enter a value and stores it in a variable called number. And then I want to pass that parameter to validateNumber(): function. But it isn't work :(
It would be fine if anyone explain me the error :)
Regards.

Here's the code:

```
def inputData(): 
    number = int(input("Enter a Number: ")) 
    print(number)
    return number 

def validateNumber(number): 
    n=2 
    while number > n:
        if number%n==0 and n!=number:
            print("Not Prime") 
            break 
        else: 
            print("Prime") 
            break 
    return number

inputData()
validateNumber()
```

[image: Here's the error code]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform the function call as follows:

```
validateNumber(inputData())
```

or

```
number = inputData()
validateNumber(number)
```

with `def validateNumber(number)` you are telling python that the function `validateNumber` must receive one parameter when it is called. But, you are not passing the parameter to it when you call it.

If you are new to programming, check this tutorial: [Python Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), to understand:

- What are functions
- How to define them
- How to use them.

Comment: Your code works :) But now its asking the prompt two times to the user to enter a number? why is that?
Given below is the output.
Enter a Number: 5
Enter a Number: 5
Prime

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee instead of pasting an image of the code, copy and paste the actual code instead into your post so I can run it in my machine and help you debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry my bad :( Here's the actual code,
def inputData():
    number = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
    return number

def validateNumber(number):
    n=2
    while number > n:
        if number%n==0 and n!=number:
            print("Not Prime")
            break
        else:
            print("Prime")
            break
    return number
inputData()
validateNumber(inputData())

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee It would be helpful if you edit your post and change the image with the actual code.

Comment: I run your code and it works for me. Check the way by which you are running the code.

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee The reason for your two times asking is  ` inputData() validateNumber(inputData())` in your previous version . You run `inputData()` twice so it  asks you twice. Appearently you have changed that. Just a small tip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value of inputData() function in some variable then pass it to second function like this

```
>> number = inputData()
>> validateNumber(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the inputted number to the validate function.

```
returned_input_number = inputData()
validateNumber(returned_input_number)
```

Also, I find it a bit odd that your validateNumber function returns a number. It might be better to return True or False (depending on if the number is valid or not). Either that, or maybe 'validate' is the wrong name for the function.